# @Produces annotation in JAX-RS

Tags: java, annotations, jax-rs

My service method Produces one of this `MediaTypes` it may produce `pdf` or `excel` file or other.

```
@Produces({"application/pdf","application/vnd.ms-excel"...
```

***My Question***

My service returns response type with `application/pdf` always even if it produces `excel`. Why?

Than I rearranged `MediaTypes`.

```
@Produces({"application/vnd.ms-excel","application/pdf",...
```

Now it's giving type `application/vnd.ms-excel` for all responses,again Why?

I am using `com.sun.jersey` API for client and getting type by the use of

```
clientResponse.getType()
```

Probably I think I misunderstood the concept of `@Produces` annotation.

*Please Clarify.*

---

*Following is code of my Service method.*

```
response = Response.ok((Object) file);//file is Object of File
response.header("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+filename);
//filename can be a.pdf b.xlsx etc
return response.build();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it said in the [documenation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e1785):

```
@GET
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public String doGetAsXmlOrJson() {
    ...
}
```

> The doGetAsXmlOrJson method will get invoked if either of the media types "application/xml" and "application/json" are acceptable. **If both are equally acceptable then the former will be chosen because it occurs first.**

Also, you can use `quality factor` for specifying which media type is more preferable: 
`@Produces({"application/xml; qs=0.9", "application/json"})`.

In any way, if you want to be sure about which media type is used, you should divide your methods into two different signatures.

Comment: Not working for me..I am using jersey 2.15.Service is returning XML by default...Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

JAX-RS methods should base the preferred content type on the value of the `Accept` header of your request. Failing that, it should default to the first specified.

While the [JAX-RS spec](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/index.html) is somewhat vague on the subject, the [Jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e1785) is very clear in describing the selection mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

The `@Produces` annotation is used by the JAX-RS implementation to bind the incoming request to one of your Resource Methods, based on the `accept` header of the request.

You can set the exact type of the response in the returned `Response` object using `ResponseBuilder#type(MediaType)` if you want to enforce one media type in particular.

If you want to match the `accept` header of the incoming request ("application/vnd.ms-excel" vs "application/pdf" in your case), you can retrieve that header by adding a parameter annotated with `@HeaderParam("accept")` in your Java method.

HTH.