# XML returns as default instead of JSON rest service

Tags: java, xml, json, rest, jersey-2.0

I have a rest api that supports returning both XML and JSON as follows:

```
@GET
    @Path("/areas/city/{cityId}")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public Response getAreaByCity(@PathParam("cityId") String cityId) {
        List<Area> areaList = //service call to get area
        GenericEntity<List<Area>> areaEntityList = new GenericEntity<List<Area>>(areaList) {};
        return Response.ok(areaEntityList).build();
    }
```

The above returns XML as default if no Accept header is defined.I want to return JSON instead..so as per the post [@Produces annotation in JAX-RS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257314/produces-annotation-in-jax-rs), I changed my service to provide quality factor. But again XML is returned by default. 
After thinking for some time, I see `Area` class which is being used is marked with `@XmlRootElement`. Is this causing issue? If yes, how to resolve it? If not, how can i return JSON as default.

Comment: I am using postman rest client. However, I tested this with SOAP UI as well..

Comment: Doing this, is returning JSON. What i want is to return JSON even if no Accept header is set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
@POST
@Consumes({  MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response post(Student s,@HeaderParam("Accept") String accept){
    if(accept!=null && accept.contains(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)){
    accept = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML;
    }else{
    accept = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON;
    }
    //Construct list
    Response.ok(list, accept).build();
}
```

Comment: You can check the accept type, from @HeaderParam; if the accept type is XML, we can create a Response with XML, else JSON.

Comment: Ya, for this kind of situations we need to include the checks, if the client isn't providing any accept type information, by default, XML is being sent.

Comment: @Pasupathi- that worked, but why providing the quality factor doesn't work as explained in the given link.

Comment: Quality factor also working, if you're using SOAP UI, please check the RAW tab of Response, and confirm me if you still get XML. I changed the service Produce annotation to @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML +"; qs=0.9", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })

Comment: Did you return an JAXB object i.e. an object marked with @XmlRootElement?

Comment: I am using Jersey 2..I checked in SOAP UI as well..in response, Content-Type: application/xml is returned which should be application/json..now sure how it is working for you..

Comment: quality factor is working..actually was testing GET api on browser and it was returning XML..i guess default accept header is xml in browser...but when i used rest client tools, then it's working fine..Thank you.

Comment: Ya by default in browser's accept types xml will be there. You can test it in SOAP UI..