# Unable to change postman Content-Type while running rest API

Tags: java, rest, postman

I am using postman to call REST API providing Content-Type as application/json and response is in JSON format only, but when I check for response header in postman it is showing as application/xml how can I change this according to my request Content-Type.

Request

[image]

Response Header :

[image]

I have tried proving `@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})` annotation in my Java action class. Also tried to override header in `HttpServletResponse (response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");` but still it is not working.

Comment: You’re looking for the [Accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) header

Comment: Yes, How can I add it from java application and not from postman request header

Comment: The Accept header needs to appear in the request. If you want your application to _only_ produce JSON, remove “application/xml” from the Produces annotation.

Comment: Actually response is dynamic that's why I have added  @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"}) . If response is json then I want application/json in response header and wise a versa

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@Produces annotation in JAX-RS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257314/produces-annotation-in-jax-rs)